# Azure resource group does not contain resources but warns that resources will be deleted

Tags: azure

I am tidying up my Azure directory and I want to delete a Resource Group.
When I drill into the resource group the screen says "No resources"
I have not set a filter.
However when I try to delete the resource group a warning appears stating that there are 11 affected resources.
The resource names contain words like "ForbiddenRequests" "LongHttpQueue"

[image]

I am the owner of the subscription

Is it safe to delete the resource group?

I am also experiencing 
[an issue if I try to create a new trial Azure account](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2016/09/15/microsoft-account-overlap-solution.aspx)

and [an issue trying to  create SQL Server databases hosted in Australia](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4eae5265-2934-4d3b-bc4a-9e63c39bc868/unable-to-select-australian-region-when-creating-a-new-sql-database-server?forum=ssdsgetstarted)

I wonder if these issues could be related.

[Update]

There is also some information about a failed deployment

[image]

[image]

[Update]
https://resources.azure.com shows

[image]

Comment: Are you a Owner of the subscription?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT  yes I am. I just updated the question to show that I am.

Comment: Hi,@kirsten , Could you post a screenshot for the affected resources when you tried to delete the resource group?

Comment: hi @WayneYang-MSFT I updated the question.

Comment: Thank you for your patient. Have you checked resources in https:// resources.azure.com ?

Comment: Ah, I am new to that url. I updated the question again.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Those "resources" are microsoft.insights alerts . You can feel free to  delete them.

Comment: how do I delete them?  Should I just go ahead and delete the resource group in Azure Portal ?

Comment: Yep, you got it. Just delete the resource group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ensure that you didn't filter any resources again, the resource group filter bar should looks like this:

[image]

Second,  clear the cache of your browser and reopen it to try again. Or you can use another Internet browser.

Also, you can go to All resources to check if those resources are already exits in you subscriptions.

Please let me know if it helps!

---

Update:

According to your screenshots, these resources are **all microsoft insights  alerts or other components**. You can check them in https://resources.azure.com . Select the resource group and extend the `microsoft.insights` and then you can find them.
This may caused by that you created Application insights or other microsoft insights to insight the resources in that group and didn't delete all of them.

> Is it safe to delete the resource group?

Yes, these alerts are not resources indeed. So you cannot see it in resource group from Azure portal.  They work with Microsoft insights such as application insights. You can delete them because the resources links to the insights are all removed.You don't need them any more.

Comment: The filter bar does look like you show. On a different computer I have the same problem. The resources do not exist anywhere except for when I try to delete the resource group.

Comment: @kirsteng Sorry ,I will do a deep test and keep you updated.

Comment: Hi,@kirsteng . Try to login resources.azure.com . Then navigate to subscriptions --> specific subscription -->That resource group --> providers --> to check if there is any deployed else resources here.(Don't click show all) NOTE: the resources in Microsoft.resources are all deployed and deleted resources , not all resources for now.